# On Windows 7 (and Windows 8.1 - don't know) is there any way to ensure the Punjabi font will be legible on a dialog's controls?

Tags: fonts, windows-7, mfc

Here is an interesting situation. My application is **MFC** based **Dialog** format. It supports nearly 40 languages, some of which are referred to as **partial** translations.

Partial translations are as the name implies. So the bulk of the GUI is still in **English** and only parts of it are translated. For the most part this looks and works perfectly fine.

However, recently I added partial translations for **Punjabi**. Now, my development platform is **Windows 10** and I think the text looks fine, albeit it a little small:

[image: Punjabi - Windows 10]

However, if I run my Virtual copy of **Windows 7** the results are much worse:

[image: Punjabi - Windows 7]

Now that is a struggle to read. All of my fonts in the application use the **MS Shell Dlg (8)** default.

I realise that I can perhaps create my own `CFont` as a member of the dialog, and apply it to the specific controls. But then I have the complication of working out the right text size to use. Since the user screen resolution etc. could be anything. I don't even know if that is the right way to go about fixing it?

So the question is:

Specifically, if the user is on Windows 7 (and maybe Windows 8.1 - not checked it) is there any way to ensure the Punjabi font will be legible on a dialog's controls?